# Cypress detects uncaught errors originated from application

Tags: cypress

My test was running successfully. I did not update anything, but suddenly my spec is failing. This is the error displayed:
[image]

The funny thing is I don't see the a.focus on my cypress code and Cypress still performs the click on the function that is failing, but then the test fails.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution.
I added

```
    // returning false here prevents Cypress from
    // failing the test
    return false
})
```

on the top of the spec as it is explained here
[Cypress Uncaught assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845493/cypress-uncaught-assertion-error-despite-cy-onuncaughtexception)